# Why does my Visual Studio says "SIGQUIT" is not defined when I pthread_kill(runTheGame,SIGQUIT);？

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, pthreads, signals

So I am a newbie of programming, and I want to write a 2048 game with a time countdown. When time is up, the timer should use pthread_kill() to end the runTheGame(), which is the function of playing game.

I searched the internert and they tell me to use pthread_kill(functionName, SIGQUIT). And you know the rest of my story: VS doesn't know SIGQUIT.

I know VS doesn't support pthread, so I followed some guides to make it works. Besides putting a .h into the path, I found out that I have to makesure the source ends with .c but not .cpp or the compiler would say there are some errors with the third parameter with pthread_create().

Furthermore, I wrote "#pragma comment(lib,"pthreadVC2.lib")" at the start of my source. If I don't do so, other problems come out.

After all these preparation, I succefully run a program that counts how many chars did _getch() captures while calculating elapsed seconds at same time in another thread.

All these information is for proving that I've (partly) correctlly installed pthread.h into VS. I thought my pthread would work nicely, god knows why the hell it has something wrong now.

```
#pragma comment(lib,"pthreadVC2.lib")
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
pthread_t runTheGame;
//***unneccessary code is hidden***
void timerTick()//function for doing countdown
{
    for (;;)
    {
        restTime--;
        if (restTime <= 0)
        {
            pthread_kill(runTheGame,SIGQUIT);//VS doesn't recognize the SIGQUIT
            if (score >= goalOfLevel[arcadeLevel - 1])
            {
                //code is not written yet
            }
        }
        _sleep(1000);
    }
}
//***unneccessary code is hidden***
void gameRunning()//Real game loop. Run by pthread_create().
{
    //***unneccessary code is hidden***
}
//***unneccessary code is hidden***
void game(int arcade)//function for initializing the game
{
    arcadeLevel = arcade;
    boardRange = 4;
    oversize = 2048;
    score = 0;
    revive = 0;
    doubleScoreOrNot = 1;
    if (arcadeLevel > 0)
    {
        restTime = timeOfLevel[arcadeLevel - 1];
        if (passivePower[0] == 1)
        {
            boardRange++;
        }
        if (passivePower[1] == 1)
        {
            revive = 1;
        }
        if (passivePower[3] == 1)
        {
            oversize = 1024;
        }
        if (passivePower[4] == 1)
        {
            score=goalOfLevel[arcadeLevel-1]/10;
        }
        if (passivePower[5] == 1)
        {
            restTime += restTime /20*3;
        }
        if (passivePower[7] == 1)
        {
            boardRange--;
            doubleScoreOrNot = 2;
        }
    }
    pthread_create(&runTheGame, NULL, gameRunning, NULL);//after all these initialization, real game starts here
}
```

Thank you for your helpings.

Comment: `SIGQUIT` is a POSIX-specific signal, it doesn't exist for Windows. Are you sure your POSIX thread library defines it? And if it does, in which header file?

Comment: Actually itis not defined in .h. But actually the whole pthread.h is not a thing of Windows. By doing all those preparations, I thought I've already made the whole thing available for my VS.

Comment: See e.g. [this `signal` function reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/signal?view=vs-2019) for a list of supported signals on Windows. And also for which header file to include for those signals.

Comment: You don't `#include <signal.h>`. Doesn't it exist in your implementation?

Comment: Are you trying to write a portable program, or will it always only run on Windows? If you only target Windows then you don't need the portability, and I suggest you use the WINAPI functions (like e.g. [`CreateThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread)) instead.

Comment: Oh and as a general hint about threads: Never kill threads directly. That doesn't give the threads any chance to exit cleanly. Use some kind of other signalling (like an atomic boolean flag) to tell the thread it should exit as soon as it can.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes! Portable. I want my grilfriend have my game on her android c compiler(name is Mobile C). Windows.h is not supported on that app.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Man, these knowledge is so complicated XD. I thought learning strings in c is already difficult enough haha.

Comment: @rici Thanks for your hint! But SIGQUIT is not defined in signal.h as well(in my computer, of course).

Answer (score 0):

The posted code is missing the statement:

```
#include <signal.h>
```

which is where the signal names are defined

The SIGQUIT also causes a core dump.  Probably not what you want.  Suggest using: SIGTERM

Comment: But actually SIGQUIT is not defined in MY signal.h as well, which is odd